# Can I delete a folder with '' (empty name) on S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket with a bunch of static assets for a website. At the top level, along with my regular `css`, `js` and `images` folders, is `` (a folder with a blank name). I might have created that folder accidentally. The 'Delete' option in the UI works with the named folders, but not with the blank folder.

**How to do I delete the blank folder?**

[image]

Comment: Double click on it. What is inside it?

Comment: @NinadGaikwad A second copy of `css` `js` and `images`. That's why I want to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coincidentally I found a similar no name folder in one of my buckets right after I read your question. There will be something inside that "folder". Navigate inside it till you find an actual file that you can delete or move. Once the folder is empty the path will no longer be valid and will stop showing up in your s3 client view.